# does mysql.connector not count as a module for mysql

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-connector

```
 File "C:\Users\marsh\data Management\LibraryManagementSystem\library.py", line 6, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
[Finished in 0.253s]
```

is the response to `import mysql.connector`. I pip installed Mysql. Any help would greatly be appreciated. I have already tried restarting program(ATOM)

Comment: You may have multiple Python installations, and pip installed in the wrong place.

Comment: no i havent updated or reinstalled python as only got this laptop yesterday??? Unless theres some other factor put in place

Comment: @maiiss can you help?